# Embedding PDF using <embed>

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to embed a PDF in my webpage using this HTML tag

```
<embed src="instructions_after_extraction.pdf#navpanes=0" style="width:500px; height:375px;" />
```

If you have noticed, I have turned off the navigation panes using `navpanes=0`. However, is there a way to specify the available buttons in the toolbar? I'm already aware that `toolbar=0` removes the toolbar from the display, but is there a way to turn off each button separately?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe such control exists. However, on a side note, I would be vary of using the embed tag in the first place. An object tag with a number of parameters is the more appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I read about the difference between the two, and you're right. I guess I'll be using <object> now

Answer (score 0):

The GUI settings with which a PDF needs to be displayed can be specified by the PDF-creation software too.